# Having @RestControllerAdvice in different jar file is not catching Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a couple of REST API's using spring boot and was thinking of decoupling the exception handling and having it as an external jar file which I can then import it into my projects and have one global exception handler logic. I created a new project for this which has a class with @RestControllerAdvice annotation and I am importing that project as a dependency in my REST API project and I see that the exception is not being handled.

This is Controller from my REST API project

```
package com.xyz.poc.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Error in hello world");
    }
}
```

This is the bootstrap class of the REST API

```
package com.xyz.poc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xyz.*"})
public class PocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Below is the build.gradle file for the REST API project, which includes the import of the jar file of the exception handler project. I am manually copying the jar file to libs folder so thats why it is referencing it in the below file.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.xyz'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/exceptionhandling-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

task listJars {
    configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
}
```

Below is the @RestControllerAdvice class, this is a different project as mentioned above and is imported as a dependency in the REST API project

```
package com.xyz.exception.exceptionhandling;

import com.xyz.exception.exceptionhandling.GenericExceptions.AuthenticationException;
import com.xyz.exception.exceptionhandling.GenericExceptions.ConflictException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
    public ServiceError handleCatchAll(Exception exception, WebRequest req) {
        logException(exception);
        return new ServiceError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exception.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { BindException.class })
    public ServiceError handleRequestBindingException(BindException exception) {
        logException(exception);

        ServiceError errors = new ServiceError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, exception.getMessage());

        for (FieldError error : exception.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.addField(new ErrorField(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        }

        return errors;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {
            TypeMismatchException.class,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
            MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
            IllegalArgumentException.class
            })
    public ServiceError handleBadRequest(Exception exception) {
        logException(exception);
        return new ServiceError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, exception.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { AuthenticationException.class })
    public ServiceError handleResponseAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException exception) {
        logException(exception);
        return new ServiceError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, exception.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { NoHandlerFoundException.class })
    public ServiceError handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException exception) {
        logException(exception);
        return new ServiceError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, exception.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { ConflictException.class })
    public ServiceError handleConflictException(ConflictException exception) {
        logException(exception);
        return new ServiceError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, exception.getMessage());
    }

    private void logException(Throwable exception) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred: " + exception.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("An error occurred", exception);
    }
}
```

this is the bootstrapper in my Exception handling project

```
package com.xyz.exception.exceptionhandling;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExceptionhandlingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExceptionhandlingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I never used `*` for scan package. Have you tried using `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xyz"})`

Comment: Try `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.from.jar"}`

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam I tried without the wildcard and I seeing the same issue

Comment: @KamilW The way you mention is actually the same as what I did, anyways I tried your way but still the same issue

Comment: How did you import second jar? Are you sure that you have it in the classpath?

Comment: And you don't need `@SpringBootApplication` in the lib project

Comment: What scope did you use to import this dependency?

Comment: @VadimBeskrovnov I am creating an executable jar file for the exception handler project and then for now importing it directly as a local dependency in my build.gradle file. I have added that file in my question

Comment: @zakSyed `ControllerExceptionHandler` is this bean ever been loaded to spring? If you try `applicationContext.getBean` it is really there?

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam Yes, I see the classes from the jar file in my project

Comment: Try to autowire `ControllerExceptionHandler` in `HomeController` and see if `ControllerExceptionHandler` is null or valid object

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam I am getting error: package com.xyz.exception.exceptionhandling does not exist on compile time

Comment: I think the way you exported your jar is wrong. If you are on eclipse, try using Export As -> Java -> JAR File

Comment: I am using Intellij. I just generated a new library project using gradle and I am running into the same issue with it

Comment: your jar is not properly imported into project @zakSyed

Comment: It was an issue with how the jar was created as well as the absolute path that I had configured in the build.gradle file was wrong. I was able to resolve it by creating a new project with the gradle init command and selecting library project and then building it and importing it by providing the correct path in the build.gradle file

Comment: Another question, if I have @RestControllerAdvice in an external jar but want to customize lets say the handling of Exception.class, will I be able to extend the class from my REST API and then override the method ?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
implementation files('libs/exceptionhandling-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

with

```
compile files('libs/exceptionhandling-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```